# How the python deal with add,sub,mul,div?

Tags: python, open-source, cpython

I create a Rational(p, q) class, and overwrite the method __add__, __mul__,__sub__, __truediv__,  __str__.
For example,

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if type(other) is Rational:
        return Rational(self.p * other.q + self.q * other.p, self.q * other.q)
    else:
        return self.value + other
```

Now my Rational can do some calculation:

```
    r1 = Rational(2,3)   # 2/3
    r2 = Rational(1,6)   # 1/6
    r1 + r2              # 5/6
    r1 - r2              # 1/2
    r1 * r2              # 1/9
    r1 / r2              # 4
```

However, when I try to do calculation between Ratioanl and float/int, it works only if the first is Rational and the second is float/int, like this:

```
    Rational(1, 4) + 0.5 # 0.75
    Rational(1, 4) * 2   # 0.5
```

If I change the order like

```
    0.5 + Rational(1, 4)
    2 * Rational(1, 4)
```

It will get a TypeError:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\hang\mypractice\rational.py", line 131, in <module>
        print(0.5 + Rational(1, 4))
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'Rational'


    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\hang\mypractice\rational.py", line 131, in <module>
        print(2 * Rational(1, 4))
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Rational'
```

I try to look up to the [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.9/Modules) source code, but I cannot get the point :(
How can I make it? How the python deal with +-*/ ?

Comment: how are we suppose to tell you what is wrong if you don't actually provide your code?

Comment: Add methods `__radd__()`, `__rmul__()`, etc. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the order of operation for \_\_add\_\_, \_\_mul\_\_, etc. methods in a custom class](//stackoverflow.com/q/34827132/90527)